# Wordpress frontend completely blank

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress-page using oxygen and WPML that woked out nicely until the end of 2023 and since the beginning of 2024 the frontend is completely blank, meaning no html-code at all is rendered on no page. The backend is still accesible and the files on the server also seem to be there still.
When I open up the dashboard and login I saw a WPML-window-alert that something moved on the site and thereby I have to take action. I therefore now deactivated all WPML-plugins and oxygen, activated a standard-theme but still the frontend is blank.

Where do I start debugging from here if the page renders really nothing at all anymore then

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

won't help I guess? But what else could I do then?

Comment: White screen of death is symptomatic of a PHP failure. Check the server error log to see what PHP is telling you.

Comment: define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); can definitely help here and would be a place to start. Instead of a blank, white screen, you are likely to see the php error that is causing WordPress to fail.

Answer (score 1):

`define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );`

In addition to comments, you can add this code in your

`wp_config.php` 
below 
`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

to record all errors in log file, and after reloading the page, you can check what error backend wrote into this file

`debug.log` 
file will placed in the `wp-content` folder